# Trying to use a select/case inside a for loop in bash

Tags: bash

I have created a for loop and wanted to prompt the user after each item when they select Yes and proceeds with the loop. So ideally the experience would be first prompted with question "Do you wish to proceed", then Yes is selected and output would be "we are at item a", then the prompt shows again asking "Do you wish to proceed?" and if Yes is selected a second time the output "we are at item b" displays. I am having the issue that it is always stuck on "item a" no matter what is inputted.

```
array_of_items=("a" "b" "c")
for i in ${array_of_items}; do
    echo "Do you wish to proceed?"
    select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
        case $yn in
         Yes)
            echo "we are at item $i"
            echo "proceeding to next item";;
         No) 
            exit;;
        esac
    done
done
```

Answer (score 3):

A `select` block will automatically repeat until it hits a `break` command (a bit like "while true"), so your `Yes)` case needs to end with a `break`.

Additionally, `$var` and `${var}` always expand to the first element of the array. You need `${var[@]}` to get all elements, like this:

```
for i in "${array_of_items[@]}"; do
   ...
done
```